# How would I add a unique-id to an existing table with iterations

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with data coming from sensors that sense data in intervals, this table schema has the next fields (simplified):

- value (string)
- sensorname (string)
- time (timestamp)
- iteration_start (bool)

Each sensor may produce 3 or more rows of data in one iteration, but only the first row will have `iteration_start = true`

The same iteration is just the rows, with the same `sensor_name` on chronological manner, until the next row with `iteration_start = true` comes.

Now, I want to add a field `iteration_id` which makes a grouping of the rows, which belong to the same iteration, so the table becomes easier for analytics purposes. 
Newer versions of the sensor already have an `iteration_id`, but how do I retro-fit the old (millions of) rows adding the `iteration_id` field?

Will these be a case for the new BQ Scripting functions? I really can't get my head around this problem.

PD: I hope I did this understandable :) (not a native english speaker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(grp), ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY sensorname, grp ORDER BY time) iteration_id
FROM (
  SELECT *, COUNTIF(iteration_start) OVER(PARTITION BY sensorname ORDER BY time) grp
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
```

You can test, play with above using [totally] **dummy** data as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '1' value, 'a' sensorname, TIMESTAMP '2019-12-03 22:11:09' time, TRUE iteration_start UNION ALL
  SELECT '2', 'a', '2019-12-03 22:11:10', FALSE UNION ALL
  SELECT '3', 'a', '2019-12-03 22:11:11', FALSE UNION ALL
  SELECT '4', 'a', '2019-12-03 22:11:12', TRUE UNION ALL
  SELECT '5', 'a', '2019-12-03 22:11:13', FALSE UNION ALL
  SELECT '6', 'a', '2019-12-03 22:11:14', FALSE UNION ALL
  SELECT '7', 'a', '2019-12-03 22:11:15', FALSE 
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(grp), ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY sensorname, grp ORDER BY time) iteration_id
FROM (
  SELECT *, COUNTIF(iteration_start) OVER(PARTITION BY sensorname ORDER BY time) grp
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
-- ORDER BY time
```

with output

```
Row value   sensorname  time                    iteration_start iteration_id     
1   1       a           2019-12-03 22:11:09 UTC true            1    
2   2       a           2019-12-03 22:11:10 UTC false           2    
3   3       a           2019-12-03 22:11:11 UTC false           3    
4   4       a           2019-12-03 22:11:12 UTC true            1    
5   5       a           2019-12-03 22:11:13 UTC false           2    
6   6       a           2019-12-03 22:11:14 UTC false           3    
7   7       a           2019-12-03 22:11:15 UTC false           4
```

Comment: looks great so far! :)
What would i change, if i dont want to count upwards inside the partition, but generate an iteration_id thats set for a full group?

Comment: so for your example, the first three lines would have the iteration_id = 1, the next four would be iteration_id = 2

Comment: ah! i think i got it! :)
For that case, i would only need the first select, so no Row-Numbers are generated based on these, right?

What would be the best way, to update the existing rows, with the new column i already added (iteration_id) of a given Date-Frame with these new generated Values?

Comment: I am sorry, i am a stack overflow newb :)
Will do so! Thank you very very much :)

Comment: sure. no problem. see you in next posts :o)

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to modify you existing table's schema to include the new 'iteration_id' column as per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas):

1. [Manually adding an empty column](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas#manually_adding_an_empty_column)
2. [Adding a column when you overwrite or append data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas#adding_a_column_when_you_overwrite_or_append_data)

If you manually create the 'iteration_id' schema field, it will be empty, you can populate it using one of the following methods:

1. [DML statement to perform a bulk update on every row](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language)
2. [Load job that overwrites the table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data)
3. [Query result that overwrites the table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#permanent-table)

if you are overwriting or appending data, you can use the following load jobs as per the [documentaion](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas#adding_a_column_when_you_overwrite_or_append_data)

1. Appending to or overwriting  using AVRO data
2. Appending to or overwriting  using Parquet data
3. Appending to or overwriting  using ORC data
4. Appending to or overwriting  using CSV data
5. Appending to or overwriting  using JSON data
6. Appending to or overwriting  using Local file